# Elasticsearch version 7 cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-mapping

I am a newbie of elasticsearch. I create a mapping using such code:

```json
PUT /my-demo1
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "dsu_sn": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "iot_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "test_suite_id": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "error_code": {
        "type": "long"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ES responses `mapper [iot_id] cannot be changed from type [keyword] to [text]` when I index a document using such code:

```json
POST /my-demo1/1
{
  "dsu_sn": "ssl123321",
  "iot_id": "550068573720395776",
  "test_suite_id": "com.example.test.wifi",
  "error_code": 2
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add `_doc` in URL while posting a document to Elasticsearch, change the URL to `POST /my-demo1/_doc/1`

Refer [removal of types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. But the error response confuses me a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for this! I was using logstash 6.x with elasticsearch 7.x in conjunction with explicit mapping templates.
So I got a related error "Cannot update parameter [norms] from [false] to [true]"

After simply adding the below to my elasticsearch output within logstash, these errors went away:
document_type => "_doc"

Answer (score 1):

I got this error becuase of a missing index alias. I deleted the index, set up the new mapping and settings, but forgot to set the alias. Then I tried to post documents to the alias...

Comment: Yes, just came across this. Elasticsearch created a new index, without a mapping (was expecting the alias to point it at an index with mapping) with the name of the alias.